# find the first number value in a row and return the corresponding date from column 4

Tags: arrays, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a list of clients in one row starting in c9 and a list of start dates from April to December starting  in G3. My first start date is 4/4/23 and the corresponding attendance is inputted in G9 The first attendance is marked with a  (1)  and entered in G9, second in H9 (1) and so forth. By December I can add up all the ones for all the clients and see the total amount attended. My problem is I am looking for a formula to find the first instance of a 1  and then look for the start date of each client. To use the example above my first client had her first instance of 1 in cell G9 and the start date is G3 (4/4/23). Each client has a different start date but if I can't find a formula that will find the first 1 in each cell and look at the start date in row 3.

I tried several functions by googling find the first number value in a row and return the date from column 4 but everything failed. I was able to find the first number but as they are all ones in each row that didn't work.

Comment: You forgot to post (as opposed to roughly describe) your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: And you still refuse to post your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot or two to give some bearing as to where everything is supposed to go mate?

Comment: I tried this formula =HLOOKUP("1", G9:CF9, 2)